# DirectX11 Load Gif texture

Tags: c++, directx-11

Few years ago, I used `D3DX10CreateTextureFromFile` to load a .gif texture to `ID3D10Resource*`. But nowdays `D3DX` is deprecated. Which function can I use to load such a format?

Comment: [One of the first things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/02/directxtk.aspx) that showed up when searching for "d3dx replacement".

Answer (score 0):

I found `DirectXTex` texture processing library:
https://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WICTextureLoader

Answer (score 0):

D3DX had a 'everything and the kitchen-sink' approach to utility code, so it was a mix of 'runtime' things that a game or application might use when it was deployed to a customer, and it had 'tools and build-time' things that are not typically part of a production build of a game or application.

You should consider using [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which contains the WICTextureLoader module. DirectX Tool Kit is intended as a replacement for usage of D3DX at runtime for games and application.

[DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) is intended as a replacement for usage of D3DX for content and build tools, although that package also contains a 'standalone' version of WICTextureLoader as well for people who don't want to make use of the DirectX Tool Kit for whatever reason.

See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression.aspx) post for some detailed history here on why there are two copies of WICTextureLoader and overlap between DirectXTex itself and this module.

Generally for D3DX replacement suggestions, see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)

For legacy DirectX SDK replacement suggestions more broadly, see:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)

[DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx)

[DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx)

[DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx)

Note a similar question was answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958213/load-texture-in-directx-11-1).